# Watch numbers add up in pygame

Tags: python, time, numbers, pygame

I am using Python 2.7.6 with pygame and i am still new to programming and pygame.Is there a way i can make it where if i have numbers, it will go to 0 to 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 to 5 instead of just 0 to 5? Like the health system in earthbound, it doesn't just drop, it ticks down one number at a time. i tried using time.sleep() in a for loop but it just paused my entire game for a second.

```
for i in range(7):
    time.sleep(.5)
    dodged += 1
```

i tired it without the time.sleep() but it was too fast to even see.

```
for i in range(7):
    dodged += 1
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `pygame.time.set_timer` for periodic events in your game (in this case the number increasing. Run this code before your event loop:

```
increase_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(increase_event, number_change_time_in_milliseconds)
```

And run this code in your loop:

```
if event.type == increase_event
    dodged += 1
```

Comment: I am not getting an error but it works the same way as before? what number do i edit to change how much it goes up? i tried changing the number_change_time variable to 10 but it works the same.

Comment: number_change_time is in milliseconds. You probably are confusing the units.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#upcount

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 200, 200

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 20)

increase_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
number_change_time = 1000 # 1 second

def main():
    pygame.time.set_timer(increase_event, number_change_time)
    global dodged
    dodged = 0

    while True:
        event_loop()
        update()

def event_loop():

    global dodged
    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            pygame.time.set_timer(increase_event, 0) #  stop the timer on keypress

        if event.type == increase_event:
            dodged += 1

def update():
    global dodged
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    numstr = str(dodged)
    mytext = font.render(numstr, True, (255,255,0))
    mytext = mytext.convert_alpha()
    screen.blit(mytext, (20, 30))

    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```